# C++ inheritance, function not replaced in child-class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a problem with inheritance in C++. The attached code produces the output "1,1," but I thought the action methods from the classes `b` and `c` replace the action method from class `a`. So I expected the output "**2,3,**". What do I have to change to get the output "**2,3,**"?

```
#include <iostream>

//Class a

class a
{
public:
    a();
    int action();
};

a::a()
{
}

int a::action()
{
    return 1;
}

//Class b

class b : public a
{
public:
    b();
    int action();
};

b::b()
{
}

int b::action()
{
    return 2;
}

//Class c

class c : public a
{
public:
    c();
    int action();
};

c::c()
{
}

int c::action()
{
    return 3;
}

//Main Programm

int main()
{
    a arr[2];
    arr[0] = b();
    arr[1] = c();

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[0].action() << ",";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to declare the method as virtual and it has to be invoked via a pointer.

Comment: In particular the line `arr[0] = b();` results in an object of type `b` being default-constructed, then cast to type `a` so it can be stored in the array. Casting to `a` means the result isn't a `b` any more, so `b::action` doesn't apply.

Comment: @Steve314 - there is no cast in the code. The value is **converted** to type `a`.

Comment: @Steve314 - it's an **implicit conversion**. A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @Pete Becker - OK, I take the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use virtual function to get the output "2,3":
first, you should `change void action();` to `virtual void action();` in class a;
second, you should use pointer to implement polymorphism;
third, you should change `arr[0]` to `arr[i]`;

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

//Class a

class a
{
public:
    a();
    virtual int action();
};

a::a()
{
}

int a::action()
{
    return 1;
}

//Class b

class b : public a
{
public:
    b();
    int action();
};

b::b()
{
}

int b::action()
{
    return 2;
}

//Class c

class c : public a
{
public:
    c();
    int action();
};

c::c()
{
}

int c::action()
{
    return 3;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    a *(arr[2]);
    arr[0] = new b();
    arr[1] = new c();

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i]->action() << ",";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Action needs to be virtual in the base class, otherwise you can't override it.

You can use the `foo() override` notation to get a compile-time check as to whether you're really overriding something.

You will have to access the derived type trough a pointer to the base type, otherwise you'll slice and do other nasty things. Also sometimes it's a good idea to also make your destructor virtual.

```
class Base { };
class Derived : public Base { };

some_container<Base*> baseOrDerived;
```

Then you can allocate both Base and Derived objects into this container. For example with `new`, although you probably want to use `std::shared_ptr<Base> or std::unique_ptr<Base>` instead of `Base*`.

Comment: If I make the action method virtual in the base class the error appears that I cannot create an array of an abstract class. But I need instances of different child-classes stored in an array. Do you have an idea how to archive that? Maybe you could correct my code because I have almost no experience with inhertance.

Comment: @Felix: Your array is going to have to be an array of (smart) pointers.

Comment: @VaughnCato My experiences with pointers are sadly also very few. So could you please write me an example how you would implement this.